# How to create serial queue in Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

In iOS I can create GCD serial queue like this:

```
let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "serialQueue")
```

Blocks are executed in a FIFO order, one block at a time. How can I do it in Android?

This is how chunk of code can be performed on the queue:

```
serialQueue.async {
```

As I [see](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) `AsyncTask` is serial: "Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution."

I guess t is FIFO, the execution.

Found [this](http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/04/07/java8-concurrency-tutorial-thread-executor-examples/) JAVA 8 concurrency tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Executor.newSingleThreadExecutor()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()). You can pass a `Runnable` or `Callable<V>` that represents the work to be done.

Comment: Any pros cons to `AsyncTask`?

Comment: @János: `AsyncTask` is specifically for scenarios where you want to do work on a background thread (`doInBackground()`), then follow up with work done on the main application thread (`onPostExecute()`). If you do not need that behavior, there is no advantage to `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 0):

There are number of options based on what your exact requirement is. If I'm getting your question correctly,  an executor is what you need. And extend it to create a SerialExecutor like below,

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html

What are these blocks ? functions ? You need to make runnable objects for the executor to execute each of your blocks